# stay in the same tab after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, django

I have a page which contains same url but a lot of tabs after I click on a tab I can see its content but right after I refresh the page tab(0) appear but I want the last used tab.
how can I do that.
this is the js code

```
<script>
    const tabBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
    const tab = document.querySelectorAll(".tabShow");
    function tabs(panelIndex){
        tab.forEach(function(node){
            node.style.display="none";
        });
        tab[panelIndex].style.display="block";
    }
    tabs(0);
    $(".tab").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you want information about the state of the page to persist across page loads then you'll need to store that information somewhere.  On the server, in the browser's local storage, in a local cookie, etc.  For this particular example local storage would probably do the job easily.  You'd just need to update that data when the state changes and read that data to update the state when the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Session Storage** or **Query parameters (search parameters)** or **Hash parameters**

**Session Storage**: can store some values by keys until the tab is closed
**Hash Parameters**: data is stored in the url. You can even save the url somewhere or share it, and when it is open the required tab will be opened
**Query Parameters**: the same as Hash Parameters but when changed the whole page refreshes

**Session Storage** solution:

```html
<script>
  const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabShow");

  const changeTab = (tabIndex) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentTab', tabIndex);

    tabs.forEach((node) => { node.style.display = "none"; });
    tabButtons.forEach((tb) => tb.classList.remove('active'));

    tabs[tabIndex].style.display = "block";
    tabButtons[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
  }

  tabButtons.forEach((tabButton, index) => {
    tabButton.onclick = () => changeTab(index)
  });

  changeTab(sessionStorage.getItem('currentTab') || 0);
</script>
```

**Hash Parameters** solution:

```html
<script>
  const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabShow");

  const changeTab = (tabIndex) => {
    window.location.hash=`tab=${tabIndex}`;

    tabs.forEach((node) => { node.style.display = "none"; });
    tabButtons.forEach((tb) => tb.classList.remove('active'));

    tabs[tabIndex].style.display = "block";
    tabButtons[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
  }

  tabButtons.forEach((tabButton, index) => {
    tabButton.onclick = () => changeTab(index)
  });

  const hash = new URLSearchParams(location.hash.slice(1));
  changeTab(hash.get('tab') || 0);
</script>
```

**Query Parameters** solution
The same as Hash Parameters solution, but with `search` instead of `hash`

Comment: omg really thank you I choosed the Session Storage and it works ... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable that is updated each time the tab is changed and then check what the variable is equal to to determine which tab should be opened by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).